# Every discrete subgroup is unimodular

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally-compact topological group. Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup [Perhaps $G$ is hausdorff in order for $\Gamma$ to be closed and therefore have a haar-measure, but It was not mentioned in the origin book].
A book I'm currently reading states trivially that $\Gamma$ must be unimodular, but I fail to understand it.

It is clear to me that **finite** sets $E_{1,2}\subset\Gamma$ with $|E_1|=|E_2|$ must have the same measure (trivial for singletons by left-invariance of $\mu_\Gamma$, and by additivity also for finite sets). therefore $\mu_\Gamma(Eh)=\mu_\Gamma(E)$ for all finite $E\subset \Gamma$).

Now, if $\Gamma$ is finite we are done.
If it is countable, we will get by finiteness of haar measure that the measure must be the zero measure, which is a troubling result by itself.
If it is more than countable, I don't know what to do but maybe follow the same argument for countable and get the same contradiction.

p.s: I also tried using outer-regularity, but it seemed much less useful.

Comment: Can you give a link to the statement you are currently reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every discrete group is unimodular. This is easy to see.
If $\Gamma$ is discrete, there is a unique Haar measure $\mu$ on $\Gamma$ such that every point has measure $1$. Then $\mu_g$, the measure obtained from $\mu$ by right translation by $g$, has the same property for each $g\in G$, so that $\mu$ is also a right-invariant measure.

On the other hand, since you are referring to a locally compact topological group $G$, there is another result (perhaps you are referring to this result):

*Proposition:* If a locally compact group has a lattice $\Gamma$, then $G$ is unimodular.

Proof: See [here](http://msc.tsinghua.edu.cn/upload/news_2012524145113.pdf), Proposition $1.3$.

Comment: I'm not referring to the second results but to the first, although the first results is indeed as a part of the proof of the second.
https://books.google.co.il/books?id=T5NgCaa1j-4C&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=2.1+Definition+a+lattice+in+G+is+a+discrete+subgroup&source=bl&ots=Vw5u0DBdke&sig=QIjMhqw9xJQiBzYF3J3FeZ956lE&hl=iw&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiK1JenrpnPAhXExxQKHT5EAWEQ6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=2.1%20Definition%20a%20lattice%20in%20G%20is%20a%20discrete%20subgroup&f=false

Comment: I do not fully understand your proof though. Why $\Gamma$ being discrete imply that all points have measure $1$? This is not obvious to me by the definition to discrete which I learned (i.e. the subspace topology is the discrete one). Also, wouldn't that mean that $\mu(\Gamma)=\infty$?

I do understand that in that case $\mu_g(h)=1$, and therefore $\mu_g(E)=|E|$ and obviously it is right-translation-invariant.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, I think I see a few of my mistakes. Let me know if I got it right:

1. since haar measure give open sets positive measure, $\mu(h)>0$ and up to a constant $\mu(h)=1 \forall h\in\Gamma$.

2. It is not a problem that haar measure is infinite. Finitness is promissed only for compact groups, and If $\Gamma$ is inifnite it is certainly not compact.

3. The only last thing is the existence of haar measure on $\Gamma$. This would be true if $\Gamma$ would be locally-compact, which would require it to be closed which would require $G$ to be hausdorff.

Am I correct? Thank you very much sir

Comment: @MathGuy The Haar measure is only guaranteed to be finite on compact sets.  In particular, for a compact group, you can guarantee finiteness of the Haar measure.  But for a countably infinite discrete group, the Haar measure doesn't have to be (and won't be) finite.  As such, by translation invariance and discreteness, each group element must have the same measure.  We can rescale so that each element has measure 1, if we want, but this is more or less an arbitrary choice.

Comment: @MathGuy Ah, we posted those comments at the same time.  You're right.  And we have existence of a Haar measure since $\Gamma$ being discrete implies that it's locally compact and Hausdorff.  I'm not sure what you're talking about with closedness in $G$ or requiring $G$ to be Hausdorff.  As far as $\Gamma$'s Haar measure is concerned, we only need a locally compact Hausdorff topology on $\Gamma$, and the discrete subspace topology from $G$ certainly satisfies that requirement.  We don't need any further restrictions on $G$ to get a $\Gamma$ Haar measure.

Comment: @MathGuy Maybe some further restrictions on the relationship between $\Gamma$ and $G$ could ensure compatibility of their Haar measures, i.e. that the Haar measure on $\Gamma$ is a restriction of $G$'s Haar measure?  But I don't know anything about this.  Certainly it's not to be expected in general.  For example, even if you have $\Gamma$ closed in $G$ and $G$ Hausdorff, their Haar measures need not be compatible.  Take, for example, $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That is a great answer, thanks @JoshKeneda. I indeed wanted closeness in $G$ (which required hausdorff, i belive) for $\Gamma$ to be locally compact. But I didn't think that it is obvious for discrete topology as you mentioned. Perhaps it is required if $\Gamma$ is a general subgroup? Thanks again you both